Spark sending LIMIT to SQL Server on display function

Update: Both my version and the version from Fred Alisson are working fine on a brand new cluster. It was a problem on my end with
dialect configuration.

I was trying to query a SQL Server with spark but I cannot get it to display the resulting dataframe as spark is sending a literal "LIMIT" to the SQL Server resulting in a SQLServerException.
The following query runs absolutly fine
df = spark.read.format('sqlserver') \
        .option('host', sql_server_host) \
        .option('port', sql_server_port) \
        .option('database', sql_server_database) \
        .option('user', sql_server_user) \
        .option('password', sql_server_password) \
        .option("dbtable", 'dbo.TestTable')
        .load()

but when running
df.display() or display(df)

I get the following error:

SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '10001'.

Upon futher inspection I can see that spark is sending the following query to the sql server which obviouly fails because SQL Server does not support LIMIT.
SELECT TestColumn FROM dbo.TestTable LIMIT 10001 

Is there anything wrong with my configuration and is there any workaround?

Running Spark 3.5.0 on databricks 14.3 LTS

isn't it: .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")

Could you use df.show() instead? This method defaults to displaying 20 rows. Can also tell it the number of rows you want to show using df.show(100) or show all rows by doing df.show(df.count())

Sounds like a bug in their included SQL Server driver. Does it still happen if you use spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "jdbc:sqlserver://...")... instead?

@siggemannen yesn't. I was working of the databricks documentation where it said you could use .format("sqlserver") . Apparently way more experimental than I expected.

@smurphy doesn't work as it will still send that limit to the sql server.

@user3657850 one thing that surprises me is how bad all these spark docs are! They're very sparse and most parrot the name of the parameters/methods

By default Spark uses "LIMIT" (SQL Server is "TOP").
What you can try:
1 - Read using JDBC connection
2 - Specify the table using a custom query
Code example for the first option:
df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
.option('url', f'jdbc:sqlserver://{sql_server_host}:{sql_server_port};databaseName={sql_server_database}') \
.option('dbtable', 'dbo.TestTable') \
.option('user', sql_server_user) \
.option('password', sql_server_password) \
.option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver') \
.load()

Code example for the second option:
query = "(SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable) AS TestTable"

df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
.option('url', f'jdbc:sqlserver://{sql_server_host}:{sql_server_port};databaseName={sql_server_database}') \
.option('query', query) \
.option('user', sql_server_user) \
.option('password', sql_server_password) \
.option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver') \
.load()

Try these ways and let me know if you need more help!

I have the same problem when using these options...

Even when you use an explicit query?
Try to use SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM your_table and send the print of the problem here so I can see the error

Yup. It will get appended to every command which does limit the output. show(), display(), ...
But as I was looking futher into it the problem has something to do with a custom dialect we are using to convert TimestampType to datetime2 for the sql server. Worked fine in a previous LTS version but somehow doesn't for 14.3. Still looking into it.

It seems display/show command by default add limit when query is executed to database.
Try using df.collect()
#Convert List[pyspark.sql.types.Row] to Spark data frame

df=spark.createDataFrame(df.collect(),schema=df.schema)

display(df)

